Output file is empty, nothing was encoded/ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1 \
          -an \
          -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 2M \
          -pass 1 -f null /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 0 \
          -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
          -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 2M \
          -pass 2 /a_pass2_best_speed1_speed0_720.webm

When you run this command, at the very beginning of the launch it displays
[out#0/null @ 0x5640cad71ec0] Output file is empty, nothing was encoded

Is it possible to fix this somehow? The fact that the file is empty at startup is a no brainer...
Would you like extra notifications or did I write something incorrectly in the command?

This "Output file is empty" is for the first pass where there is indeed no file created. But what happens after it says this, does it then encode it (in the 2nd pass)?

Thanks you.....

This "Output file is empty" is not an error, but is really informational for the first pass (since this 2 pass encoding) for what there is indeed no file created.
After this the 2nd pass should follow and properly encode the video.

How do we initiate a second pass?

See the example in the question, it was already doing a 2nd pass (by rerunning ffmpeg with the -pass 2 parameter`
